# Applescript quit after 1 minute

Tags: xcode, macos, popup, applescript

i have a very simple applescript app in xcode that just opens a window and has a button that redirects to a website. Is there a way to automatically exit the window if the user hasnt clicked the button in 60 seconds.
Here is my code

```
script AppDelegate
    -- property parent : class "NSObject"
    
    -- IBOutlets
    property theWindow : missing value
    
    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
        -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_
    
    on buttonClicked_(sender)
        open location "https://example.com"
        quit
    end buttonClicked_
    
    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
        -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
        return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_
    
end script
```

Comment: You could avoid the whole Xcode thing by just using `display dialog` with a timeout.

Comment: @red_menace i cant, im also inserting an image in the window so i have to use xcode.

Comment: You can also use accessory views, but how are you showing the window, or is everything built in the Interface Editor?

Comment: @red_menace i made the window in the .xib file that has a whole gui where u can drag buttons and images (im clearly a noob at this). I looked up everywhere but cant seem to find out how to do this

Comment: @red_menace im showing this by doing `open compiled.app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the window is being shown when the application starts up, you can just call a method/handler after a delay from the `applicationWillFinishLaunching` method.  Since you are also quitting from the button handler, that can perform double duty, for example, replace these handlers:

```
on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    my performSelector:"buttonCLicked:" withObject:me afterDelay:60
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on buttonClicked_(sender)
    if sender is not me then open location "https://example.com"
    current application's NSApp's terminate:me -- quit
end buttonClicked_
```